# Invalid colum name in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I am converting an old project which uses Accuracer database to SQL Server.

This query (under accuracer) executes ok:

```
procedure TForm1.Prebaci1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DataModule2.UniQuery1.Close;
    DataModule2.UniQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    DataModule2.UniQuery1.SQL.Text :='UPDATE TWITTER SET TWIT = TWIT + " *** prenešeno z : " +(ZA_DATUM),ZA_DATUM=:a1 where ID=:a2';
    DataModule2.UniQuery1.ParamByName('a1').asDate :=cxDateNavigator1.Date;
    DataModule2.UniQuery1.ParamByName('a2').asInteger := cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.Values[cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex,0];
    DataModule2.UniQuery1.ExecSQL;
    DataModule2.UniStoredProc1.Refresh;
end;
```

However in SQL Server it does not work - I get this erro:

> Invalid column name ' *** prenešeno z : '.

What am I doing wrong ? Something that needs particular bracketing ?

Comment: Is `*** prenešeno z : ` meant to be a string? It looks like you're trying to generate dynamic SQL. SQL Server uses single inverted commas, not double, for strings. if you need to include a a quotation inside that string, you put two of them. For example: `SELECT 'This is a string','This isn''t a Number';`

Comment: Yes its string. But when I do :  ' *** prenešeno z : '  then Delphi throws error.

Comment: Because a single `'` would end the string. This is a gess, as we have no DDL but... `'UPDATE TWITTER SET TWIT = TWIT + '' *** prenešeno z : '' +(ZA_DATUM),ZA_DATUM=:a1 where ID=:a2';` (For clarity, I used `''` not `"`)

Comment: Now I get : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. ZA_DATUM is a datetime field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already told that you need to use single quotes in SQL Server. but I think a better solution would be to use a parameter.

Note, you also need to [CAST / CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) the `datetime` (`ZA_DATUM`) column to string:

```
...
UniQuery1.SQL.Text :='UPDATE TWITTER SET TWIT = TWIT + :a0  + CAST(ZA_DATUM AS varchar(100)), ZA_DATUM=:a1 where ID=:a2';    
UniQuery1.ParamByName('a0').asString := ' *** prenešeno z : ';
...
```

Comment: Thank you ...  Is there a way to format CAST(ZA_DATUM AS varchar(100)) to date only. Now I get  *** prenešeno z : Nov 28 2017 12:00AM. I would like it to display *** prenešeno z  28.11.2017..

Comment: You welcome. Should be `CONVERT(varchar, ZA_DATUM, 104)`. take a look into the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function.

Comment: thank you once again. The only thing I cant figure out is where actually do you do the convert stuff. Is it in the query or ?

Comment: Yes instead of the CAST

Answer (score 1):

Strings are quote with ' in SQL. You are using ".
To make a single ' in Delphi just write in your string '' (two singles).

```
DataModule2.UniQuery1.SQL.Text :='UPDATE TWITTER SET TWIT = TWIT + '' *** prenešeno z : '' +(ZA_DATUM),ZA_DATUM=:a1 where ID=:a2';
```